# Remove duplicates if team email address in the recipients

Tags: vba, email, outlook

We have a team email address that we CC for most correspondence, and then we all get a copy of all emails.

The problem is when we then reply all, and a team member has already been in the email chain that person will get the email 2 times.

This is what I tried.

```
Private Sub RemoveRecipientsWhenItemSend(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim RemoveAddrList As VBA.Collection
Dim InfoAddrList As VBA.Collection
Dim Recipients As Outlook.Recipients
Dim aRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
Dim bRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
Dim i
Dim j
Dim a
Dim b
Dim info As Boolean
info = False
Set RemoveAddrList = New VBA.Collection
Set InfoAddrList = New VBA.Collection
InfoAddrList.Add "team@company.com"
RemoveAddrList.Add "member1@company.com"
RemoveAddrList.Add "member2@company.com"
Set Recipients = Item.Recipients
For i = Recipients.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set aRecipient = Recipients.Item(i)
    For j = 1 To InfoAddrList.Count
        If LCase$(aRecipient.Address) = LCase$(InfoAddrList(j)) Then
            For a = Recipients.Count To 1 Step -1
                Set bRecipient = Recipients.Item(a)
                For b = 1 To RemoveAddrList.Count
                    If LCase$(aRecipient.Address) = LCase$(RemoveAddrList(b)) Then
                        Recipients.Remove i
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
            Next
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next    

End Sub

Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
On Error Resume Next
RemoveRecipientsWhenItemSend Item
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few Debug.Print statements proved helpful.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub RemoveRecipientsWhenItemSend(Item As Outlook.mailitem)

Dim RemoveAddrList As VBA.Collection
Dim InfoAddrList As VBA.Collection

Dim Recipients As Outlook.Recipients
Dim aRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
Dim bRecipient As Outlook.Recipient

Dim i
Dim j
Dim a
Dim b

Dim info As Boolean

info = False
Set RemoveAddrList = New VBA.Collection
Set InfoAddrList = New VBA.Collection

InfoAddrList.Add "team@company.com"

RemoveAddrList.Add "member1@company.com"
RemoveAddrList.Add "member2@company.com"

Set Recipients = Item.Recipients

For i = Recipients.count To 1 Step -1

    Set aRecipient = Recipients.Item(i)

    For j = 1 To InfoAddrList.count

        Debug.Print LCase$(aRecipient.Address)
        Debug.Print LCase$(InfoAddrList(j))

        If LCase$(aRecipient.Address) = LCase$(InfoAddrList(j)) Then

            For a = Recipients.count To 1 Step -1

                'Set bRecipient = Recipients.Item(a)
                Set aRecipient = Recipients.Item(a)

                For b = 1 To RemoveAddrList.count

                    Debug.Print vbCr & " a: " & a
                    Debug.Print " LCase$(aRecipient.Address): " & LCase$(aRecipient.Address)
                    Debug.Print " LCase$(RemoveAddrList(b)): " & LCase$(RemoveAddrList(b))

                    If LCase$(aRecipient.Address) = LCase$(RemoveAddrList(b)) Then
                        'Recipients.Remove i
                        Recipients.Remove a
                        Exit For
                    End If

                Next

            Next

            Exit For

        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub


Private Sub RemoveRecipientsWhenItemSend_test()
    RemoveRecipientsWhenItemSend ActiveInspector.currentItem
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I use to remove the duplicate recipients.

```
Set olemail = olapp.CreateItemFromTemplate(OutlookTemplate)

With olemail

' other stuff 


' check duplicate recipients
' first resolve email address per global address book 
For Each Recipient In .Recipients
    Recipient.Resolve
Next

' go through each recipients and check for dup
If .Recipients.count > 1 Then
    For i = .Recipients.count To 2 Step -1
        For j = i - 1 To 1 Step -1
            If .Recipients(i) = .Recipients(j) Then
                .Recipients.Remove (i)
                i = i - 1
            End If
         Next j
      Next i
End If

end with
```